# Using results of a SqlDataReader in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I would like to get the results of my reader to be able to be used in a `WHERE` clause in another SQL command. I have tried to put the reader into a variable to use but it does not work. I've never used readers before so I do not know how they work. Can anyone give me an idea of how to get the result of the reader into there where statement? Thanks.

The code:

```
        Dim courseSelectCom = New SqlCommand("select stuff((select ','+course_name from course where school= '" & schoolSelect & "' for xml path ('')),  1, 1, '')", connection)

        Dim reader = courseSelectCom.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.Read() Then
            Dim courseVar As String
            courseVar = "%" & reader("course_name") & "%"

            Using totalStudentCom = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(student_ID) FROM student " & "course_name like @course", connection)
                totalStudentCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", courseVar)
                Dim result = totalStudentCom.ExecuteScalar()
                 MessageBox.Show("Students for course = " & result.ToString)
            End Using
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here.
**First** you should use parametrized query and not string concatenations for building sql commands
**Second** when a DataReader is opened, the connection object cannot serve another command unless you have specified the substring `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` in your connection string

```
Dim courseSelectCom = New SqlCommand("select course_name from course where school= @school", connection)
courseSelectCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@school", schoolSelect)
Dim reader = courseSelectCom.ExecuteReader()
if reader.Read() then
    Dim courseVar As String
    courseVar = "%" & reader("course_name") & "%"

    Using totalStudentCom = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(student_ID) FROM student " & _
                                "course_name like @course", connection)
        totalStudentCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", courseVar)
        Dim result = totalStudentCom.ExecuteScalar()
        MessageBox.Show("Students for course = " & result.ToString)
    End Using
End If
```

Remember that this works only if [MARS is enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answer and sorry for the late reply, haven't had a chance to have a look at the code again until now. I get the error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: course_names" when I try and run the code, how do I fix this?

Comment: "course_names" should be the name of a field from the first execute_reader. Are you sure that it exists?

Comment: I have a field "course name" (without the S) in the command if thats what you mean but changing courses to course still gives the same error. Here is the first command:

Comment: Dim courseSelectCom = New SqlCommand("select stuff((select ','+course_name from course where school= '" & schoolSelect & "' for xml path ('')),  1, 1, '')", connection)

Comment: Why don't you update the code in your question? It is better because in comments it is really difficult to spot syntax errors or other glitches

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new here, I'll do that now.

Comment: Not sure why do you need the FOR XML PATH clause, changed the answer

Comment: I was recommended to use the FOR XML PATH as sql did not have a GROUP_CONCAT command like in mysql and I needed the result of all courses that were in a school into a string. When I run your updated code I am now given the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like' on the line  Dim result = totalStudentCom.ExecuteScalar()